# Is there a way to authenticate OAUTH2.0 of google API through terminal?

Tags: authentication, command-line-interface, google-oauth, google-photos, google-photos-api

I am fetching google photos from my account using Google Photo API. Now there is a need for me to execute that php file via terminal, but the problem is that I can't authenticate with Google API in doing so. Is there a way to do this, and if yes, then how shall it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you need an interactive login for the first authentication but then you can save the token and refresh it automatically as required.

I have implemented this class in Python to do just that.

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from pathlib import Path
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from typing import List, Optional

from json import load, dump, JSONDecodeError
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# OAuth endpoints given in the Google API documentation
authorization_base_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
token_uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"


class Authorize:
    def __init__(
            self, scope: List[str], token_file: Path,
            secrets_file: Path, max_retries: int = 5
    ):
        """ A very simple class to handle Google API authorization flow
        for the requests library. Includes saving the token and automatic
        token refresh.

        Args:
            scope: list of the scopes for which permission will be granted
            token_file: full path of a file in which the user token will be
            placed. After first use the previous token will also be read in from
            this file
            secrets_file: full path of the client secrets file obtained from
            Google Api Console
        """
        self.max_retries = max_retries
        self.scope: List[str] = scope
        self.token_file: Path = token_file
        self.session = None
        self.token = None
        try:
            with secrets_file.open('r') as stream:
                all_json = load(stream)
            secrets = all_json['installed']
            self.client_id = secrets['client_id']
            self.client_secret = secrets['client_secret']
            self.redirect_uri = secrets['redirect_uris'][0]
            self.token_uri = secrets['token_uri']
            self.extra = {
                'client_id': self.client_id,
                'client_secret': self.client_secret}

        except (JSONDecodeError, IOError):
            print('missing or bad secrets file: {}'.format(secrets_file))
            exit(1)

    def load_token(self) -> Optional[str]:
        try:
            with self.token_file.open('r') as stream:
                token = load(stream)
        except (JSONDecodeError, IOError):
            return None
        return token

    def save_token(self, token: str):
        with self.token_file.open('w') as stream:
            dump(token, stream)
        self.token_file.chmod(0o600)

    def authorize(self):
        """ Initiates OAuth2 authentication and authorization flow
        """
        token = self.load_token()

        if token:
            self.session = OAuth2Session(self.client_id, token=token,
                                         auto_refresh_url=self.token_uri,
                                         auto_refresh_kwargs=self.extra,
                                         token_updater=self.save_token)
        else:
            self.session = OAuth2Session(self.client_id, scope=self.scope,
                                         redirect_uri=self.redirect_uri,
                                         auto_refresh_url=self.token_uri,
                                         auto_refresh_kwargs=self.extra,
                                         token_updater=self.save_token)

            # Redirect user to Google for authorization
            authorization_url, _ = self.session.authorization_url(
                authorization_base_url,
                access_type="offline",
                prompt="select_account")
            print('Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url)

            # Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
            response_code = input('Paste the response token here:')

            # Fetch the access token
            self.token = self.session.fetch_token(
                self.token_uri, client_secret=self.client_secret,
                code=response_code)
            self.save_token(self.token)

        # note we want retries on POST as well, need to review this once we
        # start to do methods that write to Google Photos
        retries = Retry(total=self.max_retries,
                        backoff_factor=0.1,
                        status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504],
                        method_whitelist=frozenset(['GET', 'POST']),
                        raise_on_status=False)
        self.session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
```